# How to get two android devices talking through an app on a lan using wifi

Tags: android

I have a small project I am working on and one of the technical problems I am running into is finding a easy way to get one app on one android device to push data to another app on another android device via lan.

I do not want to have to resort to the push API or other similar solutions in case there is no Internet connection.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely use Java [Sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/net/Socket.html).  Open a [ServerSocket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) on one device and connect to it using a socket on the other device.  You can then send and receive whatever data you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Is it possible to have say a tablet that could bind to 20 or so I.P's on the lan with this method?  Kind of acting like a server of sorts.

Comment: You definitely could. You can create 2 apps (one for server, one for client) or have a setting that will turn a device into a server.  Then, as the clients come online, they find the server (it would help if the user put in the server's IP) and the server would accept each connection.  There are plenty of good examples online on how to write a multithreaded server using Java Sockets.

Comment: I suspect your follow up question will be how to avoid putting the IP of the server into each client app. I suspect the best way will be to scan all of the IP addresses within your subnet (192.168.0.x or whatever the current router has) and check for the open port that your server will be listening on.